# Using two VBOs results in only the second being drawn

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to use two VBOs in a glkviewcontroller.  The first holds vertex data for triangles.  The second holds data for lines.  But, when I try to bind the second vbo the code stops drawing (or overwrites) the scene contained in the first VBO - i.e. only the lines are drawn.

In my draw method:

First I draw the triangles

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);

[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nLiveSquares*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Now I want to draw my lines

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _lineBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*4,0);

// Set the line width
glLineWidth(5.0);

// Render the line
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

How do I get both the triangles and the lines drawn?  And am I right in thinking that each should get its own VBO?

Comment: If the vertices for the triangles and the lines are the same, you should not need a second VBO for the lines. One thing I could suggest to try would be unbinding your element array buffer before drawing the array the second time glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);  Also, if you disable one or the other, can you draw just triangles or just lines?

Comment: Yes, if I disable one or the other I get either just triangles or just lines.  No, the vertices for the lines are not the same as for the triangles.

Comment: Do you have a depth buffer in play? I assume not as you are not clearing it. Second, if you reverse the calls (eg, ask for lines then triangles) what happens?

Comment: The depth buffer is disabled.  Reversing the drawing order still shows only the lines being drawn.

Comment: Alright. Seeing as the lines still draw when put first, can you isolate the exact line that is causing the triangles to not be drawn. For example, if you comment out the glDrawArrays line but leave the rest, do the triangles now draw?

Comment: Do you have blending enabled in the case where you just draw the triangles, and they render successfully? You enable blending at the end of the line drawing code. Depending on the blend function and the alpha value produced by your fragment shader, enabling blending could easily prevent the triangles from being rendered.

Comment: Also, more generally: Try a glGetError() call at the end of drawing, and see if there were any errors, if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Truly, thanks for the help.  I just solved the problem by rearranging glbindbuffer to the top before I call glVertexAttribpointer.  I'll add a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the call to `glBindBuffer` *before* `glEnableVertexAttribArray`/`glVertexAttribPointer` :

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex),     (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));
```